# Dynamic added fields not in $this->request->data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, cakephp

I use jquery to clone a few input fields but they don't show up in the post request. I've read somewhere that it is because of the validation and that fields not made with the FormHelper are removed from the request.

I added

```
$this->Security->validatePost=false;
```

to the beforeFilter function but now I get these error messages. Can someone help me :)?

EDIT: Image to text, it's unreadable =)

```
Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property LabelsController::$Security has no effect [APP\Plugin\ContentConfigurator\Controller\LabelsController.php, line 116]
Code Context
    {

        parent::beforeFilter();

        $this->Security->validatePost=false;
LabelsController::beforeFilter() - APP\Plugin\ContentConfigurator\Controller\LabelsController.php, line 116
call_user_func - [internal], line ??
CakeEventManager::dispatch() - CORE\Cake\Event\CakeEventManager.php, line 242
Controller::startupProcess() - CORE\Cake\Controller\Controller.php, line 674
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 187
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 165
[main] - APP\webroot\index.php, line 108
Warning (2): Creating default object from empty value [APP\Plugin\ContentConfigurator\Controller\LabelsController.php, line 116]
Code Context
    {

        parent::beforeFilter();

        $this->Security->validatePost=false;
LabelsController::beforeFilter() - APP\Plugin\ContentConfigurator\Controller\LabelsController.php, line 116
call_user_func - [internal], line ??
CakeEventManager::dispatch() - CORE\Cake\Event\CakeEventManager.php, line 242
Controller::startupProcess() - CORE\Cake\Controller\Controller.php, line 674
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 187
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 165
[main] - APP\webroot\index.php, line 108
```

As Requested by ndm beforeFilter functions from:
LabelsController.php

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Security->validatePost=false;
}
```

AppController.php

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    $this->Auth->allow('login');

    // Check if the model isset.
    if (empty($this->model)) {
        throw new FatalErrorException('De huidige controller heeft geen model opgegeven.');
    }

    // Set the layout to 'ajax' when the request is ajax.
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $this->autoRender = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you even have used security component or just added a line because you see this kind of error on google?

Comment: The Security component is running in the AppController

Comment: Call the parent beforeFilter.

Comment: This is my beforeFilter:

public function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Security->validatePost=false;
    }

That is what outputs above errors

Comment: Please show all your involved controllers code (the security component configuration, and all the `beforeFilter()` methods of all controllers in the chain), not just this context snippet, it's pretty likely that you are missing something, as that error can only occour in case the given property is not present, so that the magic getter `Controller::__get()` is invoked.

Comment: I'm working on a CakePHP CMS for my internship and never worked with Cake before so apologies in advance for my lack of knowledge

The Controller that is being used is here
http://pastebin.com/Jt6YAUuR

This Controller is in a plugin btw

Comment: You may have misunderstood me, I didn't mean to say _all_ the code in your controller, but just the `beforeFilter()` methods of your `LabelsController` and all controllers that are being extended (looking at the code the only other controller is `AppController`), and very important, the `$components` definition where you are setting up the security component (which is in your `AppController` as you've mentioned). And please include it in your question so that it is self-contained.

Comment: On a side note this is not how things work: `App::uses('AppController', 'Controller', 'Security');`, the `App::uses()` method takes only 2 arguments and must be used separately for every class you want to queue for autoloading. However, queueing the security component isn't necessary in case that's what you were trying to do.

Comment: I see, but I should tell my code to use Security somewhere right? Added beforeFilter functions to my question above

Comment: Yes, that's probably what @Abhishek was referring to. Please have a look at the docs: **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html** | **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#usage**

Comment: Added Security to the $components array, which I swear I thought I already did but apparently I rolled back a GIT repo. Error messages are gone now, the code is not doing what it should do but that's another issue.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

The Security component was not added to the public $components array.

```
class Controller extends AppController
{
    public $components = array('Security');
}
```